# How to Completely Simplify the Derivative of $\sqrt{16-x^2}-4\cos^{-1}(x/4)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I am trying to completely simplify the derivative of the following function:

[image]

So far, I have gotten the answer:

[image]

Apparently this is not simplified enough.

Does anyone know how to simplify this further, if it is at all possible?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: $ \frac d{dx} (cos^{-1}x) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Comment: I think you have mistaken the inverse cosine for the secant function

Comment: You seem to have treated $\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac x 4\right)$ as if it were $\left( \cos\left(\dfrac x 4\right) \right)^{-1}$.  But in fact in conventional usage $\text{“}\cos^{-1}\text{''}$ means the arccosine function --- i.e. the inverse function. See my answer below. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have treated $\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac x 4\right)$ as if it were $\left( \cos\left(\dfrac x 4\right) \right)^{-1}$.  But in fact in conventional usage $\text{“}\cos^{-1}\text{''}$ means the arccosine function --- i.e. the inverse function.

We have
$$
\frac d {dx} \arccos x = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.
$$

Use that.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \frac{d}{dx} \left(\sqrt{16-x^2}-4\cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{4})\right) \\[10pt]
= {} &\frac{d}{dx} \left(\sqrt{16-x^2}\right)-\frac{d}{dx} \left(4\cos^{-1} \left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{2\sqrt{16-x^2}}\cdot(-2x)+\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{16}}} \cdot \left(\frac{-1}{4}\right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{-x}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}-\frac{4}{\sqrt{16-x^2}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{-(4+x)}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}=\frac{-(4+x)}{\sqrt{(x+4)(x-4)}}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{(x-4)}}.
\end{align}

I think this is right, double check.

Comment: On Wolfram Alpha the answer says (4-x)/sqrt(16-x^2)

Comment: Your last "equals" is not correct. Also, when you use the chain rule at the end of the third line, it should just be positive $\frac14$, not negative. Also somehow $16-x^2$ became $x^2-16$ in your next-to-last "equals". These three corrections make it agree with what @Kelsey says.

Answer (score 0):

use the substitution x=4cos(z).

Answer (score 0):

The fully simplified answer is (4-x)/(sqrt(16-x^2)).

Simplify the (4cos^-1(x/4))' and you get -4/(sqrt(16-x^2)).

Subtract that from 1/(sqrt(16-x^2)), and you get (4-x)/(sqrt(16-x^2)).